# How to select data from 2 tables by date

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:

In this table I have all employees:

> Employe (id_employe, name, tel)

In this table I have all employees who are present:

> Present (id_present, date, #id_empoye)

Now, I want to select all employees who are absent (all of employees who are not in the table present) with the date of absence.

I'm sorry for by bad English, and I want a help please!

Here's my sql query:

```
select id_employe, date from employe, absence where id_employe not in
(select id_personnel from absence group by date) group by id_employe
order by date asc;
```

Comment: not sure you can do this as you have no date value for absent employees

Comment: To elaborate on Tom's comment - you need somthing like present.date=curdate() - and your GROUP BY either makes no sense or isn't necessary.

Comment: the objectif was to insert all of absents into the table Absent automatically at 17:00 if there are not insert yet but i've no idea so now i'm trying to resolve my problem with executing this query.

Comment: In order to produce a list of employees not present on a date range, you would need a table containing the dates in the range. Then you could do a join between the employees and present and the dates where the rows in present are null.

Comment: If you just want a list for a specific date, then you can do that without the date table.

Comment: you mean if i have 1 month i must to insert the 30 days in the table ? it take a lot of memory

Comment: You have quite a few databases tagged, which one specifically are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you first want to do is use a subquery to get all of your employees with a record for every day that was a work day. I am assuming that if any one person showed up for work that day, it was a work day. So, I select every distinct work date and join it onto every employee. I say `ON 1=1` because that condition is always true and will give me a record for every employee and the work day.

Then, I take that temp table and I join on the Present table. If an employee was present on a work day, he will have a record joined on from the Present table, so I can look for only records where there was no join, i.e. `p.id_present IS NULL`.

```
WITH WorkDateTable AS (
   SELECT e.id_employe, p.work_date
   FROM Employe e LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT work_date FROM Present) p ON 1=1)
SELECT wd.id_employe, wd.work_date AS AbsenceDate
FROM WorkDateTable wd
LEFT JOIN Present p ON p.work_date = wd.work_date AND p.id_employe = wd.id_employe
WHERE p.id_present IS NULL
ORDER BY AbsenceDate, wd.id_employe
```

Note that `date` is a reserved word and you cannot use that for a field, that is why I changed it to `work_date`. Your final result is a list of work dates and the ID of who was absent on that day.

If you want to know who was absent on a particular date or range of dates, you just need to add a clause to the WHERE statement at the end.

**EDIT:**
MySQL does not support the use of the WITH clause. Therefore, move the statement in the WITH to inside the FROM statement like this:

```
SELECT wd.id_employe, wd.work_date AS AbsenceDate
FROM (SELECT e.id_employe, p.work_date
   FROM Employe e LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT work_date FROM Present) p ON 1=1) wd
LEFT JOIN Present p ON p.work_date = wd.work_date AND p.id_employe = wd.id_employe
WHERE p.id_present IS NULL
ORDER BY AbsenceDate, wd.id_employe
```

This query should work for either MySQL or Oracle searches.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear answer but before executing the request, I noticed that there is a closing parenthesis that is missing. Where do i put it ?

Comment: After the `1=1`. Sorry for the typo, I edited the code above.

Comment: Which database program are you using?

Comment: i use Mysql database

Comment: Try the updated answer. Also, when you are posting your question make sure you tag the correct database. You had MySQL, Oracle, and PHP tagged when really you only wanted MySQL. I gave you an Oracle answer at first based off of that and it didn't work in MySQL.

Comment: it's working !! thank you very much and thank you for the advice too. I will do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want the employees who are not present *on a particular day*, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT id_present FROM present WHERE id_employee = e.id_employee AND date = <date>
);
```

This would give you employees who are absent on `<date>` date. As we are querying for one date only, no sorting is needed.

Comment: it's not false but when i have 1 month and i want the employees who are not present foreach day of this month, i can't spécify the date

Comment: In that case, `date = <date>` becomes `date BETWEEN <date1> AND <date2>`. However, you still can't sort by date as there is no date in the result.